# How to make the TV tuner in the Dell Mini 1010 work?

Tags: dell, tv, tv-tuner, dell-mini-10

I need some help in fixing up the TV tuner in my Dell Mini 10.10 in Ubuntu. It worked in Windows with Dell's default Dell Digital TV. I've tried using Kaffeine but that didn't work.

Comment: Please, update the description adding the output of "lsusb" and "lspci -nn". This way we can find out the device ID and then search for it. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at these answers, referring to TvTime and MeTV, of which my favorite is the TvTime, that is working like a charm in the majority of the TV Tuners that I have tested, PCI, PCI-X, USB.

1. [How to scan for analog cable channels on a DVB-T USB tuner?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/45357/how-to-scan-for-analog-cable-channels-on-a-dvb-t-usb-tuner/45391#45391)
2. [Can anybody help me to make Kworld UB445-Q TV tuner work?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/58547/can-anybody-help-me-to-make-kworld-ub445-q-tv-tuner-work/58636#58636)

Dropping `tvtime --help` in a terminal will provide you with enough information about tvtime available parameters. Drop `man tvtime` and you will have a more informative help text.

If you experience problems after trying tvtime, please drop in your original question the results of tvtime if an error appears. Additionally, try adjusting the parameters to what better fits your incoming TV signals, such as the proper device where to gather signals from, tv aspect ratio, etc. if you experience Audio issues when trying TVTime (which I can bet you won't), drop the

`tvtime | arecord -D hw:1,0 -r 48000 -c 2 -f S16_LE | aplay -`

in a terminal and let's see what happen.

You may wish to make sure what your video device is but you can also try gathering signals from different devices, using the --device parameter, which will make tvtime terminal's command look like:

`tvtime --device=/dev/video0 | arecord -D hw:1,0 -r 48000 -c 2 -f S16_LE | aplay -`

Change /dev/video0 for /dev/video1...video2, etc. according to your input device. It is all about to play with the parameters and you will have TV Signals working like a charm in your computer.

If you need further information don't hesitate to drop a comment.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

This might help you.

There has been a bugfix in Intrepid for the Dell TV base on sms1xxx.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/302509?comments=all

Nevertheless it would be usefull to get some additional information about your card.