# Getting a Conexant CX23885 TV Capture Card working

Tags: 11.04, video, capture

I'm new to Linux, and am trying to get my Capture Card working on 11.04.

The only command that I know to run to find out any information is `lspci`, which tells me that I have

```
02:00.0 Multimedia video controller: Conexant Systems, Inc. CX23885 PCI Video and Audio Decoder (rev 04)
```

I've looked at using Me TV, but haven't worked out how to configure it for my card, or what I need to do to get it running.

I'm not fussed on what software I use to run the Capture Card, but I've currently got only Me TV installed.

Edit: When I run tvtime, I get the following errors:

```
videoinput: Cannot open capture device /dev/video0: No such file or directory
mixer: find error: Success
mixer: Can't open mixer default, mixer volume and mute unavailable.
mixer: Can't open device default/Line, mixer volume and mute unavailable.
Segmentation fault
```

Comment: Are you trying to capture video, or watch TV?  I think your Conexant CX23885 may be a video capture (decoder) card and not a TV turner card, in which case you can use `VLC` to view the video stream from capture devices. Applications like MeTV will be looking for a DVB-* digital tuner, or analog tv tuner cards.  Also, do an `ls -l /dev/video*` - your card may not always be video0, and you may have to configure software to use another device such as video1.

Comment: Thanks drgrog. I'm fairly sure it's both a TV Tuner and a Video capture card. I definitely have had it picking up TV when I had Windows installed. It has the connection for the tv antenna, as well as S-Video, and a yellow RCA input. I'd love to get the TV working, but I am actually interested in the video capture side of things.

Im at work right now, but I'll give these things a try when I get home. Thanks heaps all.

Answer (score 1):

The Internet suggests you probably need to download and compile a newer version of `v4l-dvb` (the library and drivers for several DVB cards.

[This walkthrough](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1648472) is for the Hauppauge 1250 but it's based around the same CX23885 chip. This *might* work.

Worth a shot if you don't find any easier options.

Answer (score 0):

Install TVtime television viewer.  It is in the software centre.  This is working for me -even in S video capture.  Good luck

Comment: Thanks Julien. I tried TVTime, but it can't find my capture device. I've edited the question to reflect the error I was getting.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this: [How to scan for analog cable channels on a DVB-T USB tuner?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/45357/how-to-scan-for-analog-cable-channels-on-a-dvb-t-usb-tuner/45391#45391) With special attention to the comments.

What you are receiving from TVTime is a wrong redirection to the appropriate device, which is leading tvtime to `/dev/video0`, if you are having a webcam, usb plugged or embedded then tvtime is trying to acquire images from the webcam instead of the TV Tuner. Try changing this value with `/dev/video1`, `/dev/video2` or whatever it works for you.

In the comments and experiences on my answer to the [How to scan for analog cable channels on a DVB-T USB tuner?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/45357/how-to-scan-for-analog-cable-channels-on-a-dvb-t-usb-tuner/45391#45391) question, there are further details which may be useful for you.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I have the Hauppauge HVR-1250.  The HVR-1250 has the Conextant CX23885 drivers.  It works out of the box for digital ATSC tuner capture with Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, which has kernel 3.2.0.  In the `/dev` folder it shows as `/dev/dvb`.  The analog capture (for the composite and S-Video, not the analog tuner) is supported in kernel versions 3.5.5 and above.  I installed kernel 3.5.5 in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and I can record Digital HDTV OTA from my antenna and analog capture from my cable receiver box via the composite cable.  The analog driver shows as `/dev/video0` in the `/dev` folder.

I believe the Hauppauge ImpactVCB-e also uses the cx23885 drivers.  It looks like the HVR-1250 OEM (01187) but without the tuner.