# How do I install a Gadmei TV Tuner (UTV380)

Tags: tvtime

How do I install a tv tuner Gadmei UTV380 (Hybrid). I've been searching around the internet.

Everytime I run TVTime it always detects my webcam as a Video Source.

Comment: This is a real question. This issue happens and is different than other questions. People shouldn't down vote it nor mark it to close. I Upvoted your question. Good luck my friend.

Comment: well to be fair: the question was a mess before I edited it @GeppettvsD'Constanzo

Comment: thankyou Rinzwind : My English is really bad ( i still learning )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have more than a video source (which seems to be your case), you must specify which one is going to be used by `tvtime` in order to get the images.

In order to know which are your video sources you can drop this in a terminal: `ls -l /dev/video*` and you must have an output like this:

```
geppettvs@DYLAN:~$ ls -l /dev/video*
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81, 0 2012-04-17 19:53 /dev/video0
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81, 1 2012-04-17 19:53 /dev/video1
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81, 2 2012-04-18 17:54 /dev/video2
geppettvs@DYLAN:~$
```

Then you must try with each different video source, tvtime usually starts from 0, so you try from `/dev/video1` with this command in a terminal `tvtime --device=/dev/video1`

If everything is ok then you'll see the TV signal in a window. If it drops an error please edit your question with the output of your terminal in order to edit this answer with an advice/solution.

- ***Expected issues:*** Video but no sound. Be warned.

> Additionally, if you face sound issues or no-sound while playing the
>   tv station, just try this in a terminal, change the 48000 value for
>   whatever your broadcast can stand for, in certain cases 32000 is good
>   enough but it depends on your tv tuner.
>
> `tvtime --device=/dev/video1 | arecord -D hw:1,0 -r 48000 -c 2 -f S16_LE | aplay -`

Check this out: https://askubuntu.com/a/45391/9598 and don't forget to use the proper 
`--device=/dev/video1` when needed.

Good luck!