# Recording video with audio from webcam?

Tags: sound, video, webcam

I've tried cheese and wxCam and both of those record the video fine, but there is no audio in the videos. How can i record a video from my webcam with audio as well?

Comment: Take a look at the answer on this question http://askubuntu.com/q/150718/9598 and let us know if this works for you. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem with cheese (that is, video was fine, but no audio).

I tried out guvcview based on [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/186021/121193). This didn't work either, but then I remembered something about USB 3 ports not working with devices like webcams sometimes, so I moved it to a USB 2 port.

Everything worked in guvcview just fine then. The webcam appeared as a new audio device ("USB Audio"). guvcview seems like a neat little application, with a lot of options for how to record from the cam.

(I tried cheese again to see if it was purely the USB 3 port as the cause, but it still didn't work.)

Answer (score -1):

Try changing the API input on gucview to pulseaudio. That just worked for us.