# How to capture from TV card using mencoder?

Tags: 12.10, tv, mencoder

How do I capture from tv card (`/dev/video0`) using mencoder?
I tried with

```
 mencoder -tv driiver=v4l2:width=640:height=480:norm=pal_nc:inpu t=1:chanlist=us_cable:channel=13 -ffourcc DIVX -fps 25 -ovc lavc -lavcopts vcodec=mpeg4:vhq -oac mp3lame -lameopts cbr:br=128 -endpos 30 -o outfile.mpg tv://
```

But, it does not work I get the following error:

```
MEncoder svn r34540 (Ubuntu), built with gcc-4.7 (C) 2000-2012 MPlayer Team
Error parsing option on the command line: -tv

Exiting... (error parsing command line)
```

Comment: Check out this answer: http://askubuntu.com/a/156496/9598. It is based on a script but does the TV card video capture easy using mencoder. Good luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The options on mplayer/mencoder can be confusing. I can't say that I understand them all yet myself, but I found a script at 
http://easycap.blogspot.ca/p/easyview-n-cap.html
that guides you through the startup parametes and then sets up a command line to do what I think you want to do.

Offhand, I'd say you have a type in the driver parameter (it should be driver, not drilver) and you are missing the device parameter (driver=/dev/video0)