# vhs capture devices

Tags: sound, video, video-conversion, video-capture-card

I have a VHS capture device ecap303 from climaxdigital used on windows 7  i am new to ubuntu but have used the command lsusb with the device connected and come up with

ID EBIA : 2861 EMPIA TECH INS

i understand that a driver for this device is written into ubuntu 12.10 but what software do i need to use the device to copy vhs tapes and make a dvd copy
 eg could i use mplayer or vlc media player

i hope you can help or suggest a better capture device that might be better

i have tried tvtime and can see video both from a vcr and from a freesat box but can not get sound despite trying the recommended steps in the reply can you make any other suggestions

```
malcolm@malcolm-Inspiron-One-19A:~$ ls -l /dev/video*
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81, 0 Nov 18 17:22 /dev/video0
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81, 1 Nov 18 17:25 /dev/video1
malcolm@malcolm-Inspiron-One-19A:~$ tvtime --device=/dev/video1 | arecord -D hw:1,0 -r 48000 -c 2 -f S16_LE | aplay
Running tvtime 1.0.2.
Reading configuration from /etc/tvtime/tvtime.xml
Reading configuration from /home/malcolm/.tvtime/tvtime.xml
Recording WAVE 'stdin' : Signed 16 bit Little Endian, Rate 48000 Hz, Stereo
Playing WAVE 'stdin' : Signed 16 bit Little Endian, Rate 48000 Hz, Stereo
mixer: find error: Success
mixer: Can't open mixer default, mixer volume and mute unavailable.
mixer: Can't open device default/Line, mixer volume and mute unavailable.
videoinput: Aspect ratio: 0.915254
videoinput: Aspect ratio: 0.915254
Thank you for using tvtime.
```

thanks regards malc

***tvtime without audio request***

```
malcolm@malcolm-Inspiron-One-19A:~$ tvtime
Running tvtime 1.0.2.
Reading configuration from /etc/tvtime/tvtime.xml
Reading configuration from /home/malcolm/.tvtime/tvtime.xml
videoinput: Driver won't tell us its norm: Invalid argument
videoinput: Can't get tuner info: Inappropriate ioctl for device

Your capture card driver: uvcvideo [Integrated_Webcam_1.3M/usb-0000:00:1d.7-2/197895]
does not support full size studio-quality images required by tvtime.
This is true for many low-quality webcams.  Please select a
different video device for tvtime to use with the command line
option --device.

retrying with: /dev/video1
mixer: find error: Success
mixer: Can't open mixer default, mixer volume and mute unavailable.
mixer: Can't open device default/Line, mixer volume and mute unavailable.
videoinput: Aspect ratio: 0.915254
videoinput: Aspect ratio: 0.915254
Found "USB Device 0xeb1a:0x2861 : USB Audio (hw:1,0)"
Thank you for using tvtime.
malcolm@malcolm-Inspiron-One-19A:~$
```

***tvtime with audio request***

```
malcolm@malcolm-Inspiron-One-19A:~$ tvtime | arecord -D hw:1,0 -r 48000 -c 2 -f S16_LE | aplay -
Running tvtime 1.0.2.
Reading configuration from /etc/tvtime/tvtime.xml
Reading configuration from /home/malcolm/.tvtime/tvtime.xml
Recording WAVE 'stdin' : Signed 16 bit Little Endian, Rate 48000 Hz, Stereo
Playing WAVE 'stdin' : Signed 16 bit Little Endian, Rate 48000 Hz, Stereo
videoinput: Driver won't tell us its norm: Invalid argument
videoinput: Can't get tuner info: Inappropriate ioctl for device

Your capture card driver: uvcvideo [Integrated_Webcam_1.3M/usb-0000:00:1d.7-2/197895]
does not support full size studio-quality images required by tvtime.
This is true for many low-quality webcams.  Please select a
different video device for tvtime to use with the command line
option --device.

retrying with: /dev/video1
mixer: find error: Success
mixer: Can't open mixer default, mixer volume and mute unavailable.
mixer: Can't open device default/Line, mixer volume and mute unavailable.
videoinput: Aspect ratio: 0.915254
videoinput: Aspect ratio: 0.915254
Thank you for using tvtime.
```

I have tried as suggested and still get the error messages copied above but ofcourse without the referance to my internal web-cam but still no sound i wonder if my capture device will work with ubuntu

regards

```
malcolm@malcolm-Inspiron-One-19A:~$ ls -l /dev/video*
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81, 0 Nov 18 17:22 /dev/video0
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81, 1 Nov 18 17:25 /dev/video1
malcolm@malcolm-Inspiron-One-19A:~$ tvtime --device=/dev/video1 | arecord -D hw:1,0 -r 48000 -c 2 -f S16_LE | aplay
Running tvtime 1.0.2.
Reading configuration from /etc/tvtime/tvtime.xml
Reading configuration from /home/malcolm/.tvtime/tvtime.xml
Recording WAVE 'stdin' : Signed 16 bit Little Endian, Rate 48000 Hz, Stereo
Playing WAVE 'stdin' : Signed 16 bit Little Endian, Rate 48000 Hz, Stereo
mixer: find error: Success
mixer: Can't open mixer default, mixer volume and mute unavailable.
mixer: Can't open device default/Line, mixer volume and mute unavailable.
videoinput: Aspect ratio: 0.915254
videoinput: Aspect ratio: 0.915254
Thank you for using tvtime.
```

regards malcolm

Comment: Hello, your question has been answered in detail in this previous question: http://askubuntu.com/q/150718/9598 Good luck!

Comment: Ok, look. This site is not a "forum-like" support place. Thus I need to drop an answer for your question. Unfortunately it seems that you have 2 questions here: 1.- How to gather both audio and video in the same stream and 2.- How to capture the embedded stream in a video file. If you don't mind, I am going to drop a "progressive" answer, which will be modified depending on the results of your test to include additional details on how to solve your issues.

Comment: We need the terminal output in order to see what the error mesage related to the audio is, malcolm. Maybe we are attempting a high bitrate or samplerate that the sound device won't play. Please add the results of your terminal output when running the command with the video1 device. Thank you

Comment: Ok I see you didn't include the last `-` in the `tvtime` command, which may result in no sound when attempting to gather both video and audio from the same input. The complete command is `tvtime --device=/dev/videoX | arecord -D hw:1,0 -r 48000 -c 2 -f S16_LE | aplay -` Please make sure you include every space, every symbol and every dash in the command and inform if the problem persist. Thank you

Comment: sorry dislexic keyboard  tried again with correct terminal line but still no sound  i note that thec terminal o/p refers to sterio sound but tvtime setup is for mono could this be my problem

Comment: Hello, sorry but I didn't notice your answer here. Ok, maybe that's the problem. Then change the `-c 2` for `-c 1` in order to make the sound monoaural. Run it as this: `tvtime --device=/dev/videoX | arecord -D hw:1,0 -r 48000 -c 1 -f S16_LE | aplay -` and please inform if you succeed. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

***As I mentioned in a comment to this question, this answer will be modified depending on the results of @malcolmelliot in order to provide the right support for his issues. (Sorry, comments are too limited.***

### Step 1 - Finding the video device.

Ok, first we need to make sure that tvtime is using the proper device to gather both audio and video. Remember that you can have 2 or more video devices, some of them won't embed audio (like webcams) and some yes.

You are receiving an error message which includes the next portions of text:

```
Your capture card driver: uvcvideo [Integrated_Webcam_1.3M/usb-0000:00:1d.7-2/197895]
does not support full size studio-quality images required by tvtime.
This is true for many low-quality webcams.  Please select a
different video device for tvtime to use with the command line
option --device.
```

Please note that the error message clearly refers to your **"Integrated_Webcam_1.3M/usb-0000:00:1d.7-2/197895"** which is -indeed- your computer's webcam. (maybe a laptop embedded webcam? based on the 1.3M data)

So we need to check how many devices we have in our system in order to run some testing with'em. In order to know this information we'll drop the next command in a terminal:

```
ls -l /dev/video*
```

Results should be like this:

```
geppettvs@DYLAN:~$ ls -l /dev/video*
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81, 0 2012-04-17 19:53 /dev/video0
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81, 1 2012-04-17 19:53 /dev/video1
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81, 2 2012-04-18 17:54 /dev/video2
geppettvs@DYLAN:~$
```

In my case, I have 3 video devices, of which one of them is the USB TV Tuner that I use for watching/recording live TV Shows/VTR/VCR/RF-DVD/Video converter and other RF Signals.

You should check any of them and make notes of your results in order to continue. Simply run your testing via `tvtime --device=/dev/video0` in a terminal. do it also for `tvtime --device=/dev/video1` (which may result in an error as we see that this device is your webcam) and other instances like `tvtime --device=/dev/video2`, `tvtime --device=/dev/video3`, etc.

When you find the exact tvtuner device, make sure you use it to follow the next process.

### Step 2 - Gathering both audio and video in the same stream.

Now, we need to make sure you can gather both audio and video in the same stream. If you are dropping `tvtime` in a terminal and getting video with no audio, then we need to instruct the sound system to get the audio and reproduce it simultaneously. This can be achieved by dropping in a terminal the next command:

```
tvtime --device=/dev/videoX | arecord -D hw:1,0 -r 48000 -c 2 -f S16_LE | aplay -
```

Please note that you should replace `/dev/videoX` with the proper device you found in the previous step.

This will result in both audio and video synced and embedded in the same stream. If so, then we can continue with the capture steps.

Please inform if you succeed in order to continue.

Good luck!

Comment: typed in suggested but still no sound

Comment: I will need the terminal output when running tvtime with and without the arecord. Please.

Comment: to geppettvs please find terminal outputs added to original question regards

Comment: Thank you malcolm, I see your terminal output and added something to this recipe. We're going on the right way. Please be patience and run your testing and I am sure we'll succeed. :)

Comment: i  have tried as suggested capture devoce is dev/video1 so i added lines you gave me but still no sound   do i need a different capture device  regards

Comment: Hello @malcolmelliott I just recently noticed your deleted answer. Sorry for delaying. How are you doing now video capture? Please have a look at this answer, http://askubuntu.com/a/156496/9598 which may provide some help on such task and let me know if you succeed. You can see my profile at http://askubuntu.com/users/9598/geppettvs-dconstanzo?tab=profile for contact details if you need further assistance. Good luck!