# Does Hauppauge WinTVR 900H work with Digital TV in the UK

Tags: tv-tuner

I have been trying to sort out my Hauppauge WinTV 900H USB Tuner. Here in the UK, we do not have Analogue TV any more as we are fully converted to digital.

I have had this working in Windows a while ago, but am having no joy in Ubuntu 13.04 all I get is a blue screen and no settings for the UK. Can anyone advise me how to set this up on my laptop.

I have tried:

- [Does Hauppauge WinTV HVR-900 (r2) [USB ID 2040:6502] work with ubuntu 12.04 LTS?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/187497/does-hauppauge-wintv-hvr-900-r2-usb-id-20406502-work-with-ubuntu-12-04-lts)
- I am using TVTime
- I have also read [this page](http://www.linuxtv.org/wiki/index.php/Hauppauge_WinTV-HVR-900H), which makes me think that this unit can only receive Analogue signals, which are no longer transmitted in the UK (which could be my problem!)

[image: WinTV HVR 900H]

**Laptop Specifications**:

1. Intel® Core™ i3-2350M CPU @ 2.30GHz × 4
2. Intel® Sandybridge Mobile
3. 6MB RAM

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Uhm, you should check if you have the firmware and if not you should download it by doing these two commands in terminal

```
cd /lib/firmware
sudo wget http://www.steventoth.net/linux/hvr1400/xc3028L-v36.fw
```

Then if it's still not working try with other programs like MeTv or TvHeadend which is a little bit complicated at first but once you configure it your decoder is going to go faster and stabler, plus by configuring tvheadend you can also use your DVB decoder in XBMC or other Media Center and set programme recording directly from Tvheadend web interface.